# Multiple refresh trying to login with keycloak

Tags: angularjs, keycloak

I'm trying to authenticate users on a gui in angularJS 1.6 with keycloak 4.8.3

The authentication seems to be ok but there is an undefinite number of refresh before authentication.

I've tried with an older version of keycloak. the problem is still the same. The problem seems to appear calling the login method of keycloak but I don't know how to fix it

```
<script src="http://10.91.129.228:8080/auth/js/keycloak.js"></script> 
    <script>
        var keycloak = Keycloak();


            keycloak.init(
                { onLoad: 'login-required' ,
            }
            ).success(function(authenticated) {
                if(authenticated){
                    console.log("user connected")
                }
                else{
                    console.log("no user is connected")
                }
            }).error(function() {
                console.log("Keycloak : failed to initialize")
            });

    </script>
</head>
```

Comment: I have a similar problem with JS adapter: I start my angular application, the keycloak login page appears, I exec the log in correctly and after that ( every ten seconds ) the page refreshes itself ( without the keycloak login page appears, because I'm already logged in). I search a lot on the internet to find out which is the problem but I can't find the solution.